# Laravel eloquent relations. 3 tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a 3 tables in my db:

```
Students:
  -id
Exams:
  -student_id
  -code_discipline
  -rating
Disciplines_names:
  -code_discipline
  -name_discipline
```

And on controller i want something like this:

```
public function show($id)
{
  $student = Student::find($id);

  $student->exam()->discipline();
}
```

How i can manage this eloquent relationships?

Comment: [Looks like a duplicate of another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59005992/laravel-eloquent-relations-3-tables) asked a few hours previously from a different account?

Answer (score 0):

from Student Model declare a relationship with Exam Model , then from Exam model declare a relationship with discipline.